# Can the Sync Centre automatically resolve sync conflicts?

Tags: networking, sync, sync-center

I use a small domain network at home, to ease with backups (files are stored on the server, even user accounts). Due to a faulty network switch (that is being replaced), the connection to the domain is sometimes terminated and as a result files do not get synced across:

[image]

I can resolve the sync conflicts, but selecting all of them and clicking "Resolve" takes a while on "Resolving Conflict" due to the amount of files created while offline:

[image]

When the prompt *eventually* pops up, I am asked if I want to "Keep" (sync files to the server, overwriting any files with the same name), "Replace" (replace with the files from the server", or "Keep Both Versions" (rename one of the files):

[image]

I'd like the files to sync with the "Keep" option automatically without having to do anything (i.e, when a conflict with "Offline Files" is raised, automatically sync as "Keep" when the server is available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [automatic resolution of file conflicts is possible via a registry tweak](http://stealthpuppy.com/configuring-an-automatic-resolution-policy-for-offline-files-in-windows-7/):

1. Fire up the Windows Registry Editor (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, "regedit");
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\NetCache`;
3. Right-click in the main window pane, point to "New", and then click  "Key". You'll be required to give it a name; call it `SyncConflictHandling`.

[image]

4. Right-click on `SyncConflictHandling`, point to "New", and then click "Expandable String Value". Name it the root of your network share where domain user accounts are stored (for instance `\\server\fileshare`);
5. Right click > Modify > Set the value to `1` (keep local state)

Comment: I edited your guide, it seems you missed a key point in step three (name of the new key) :)